# Executing .exe file in Java in separate directory

Tags: java, executable, working-directory, launching-application

I want to launch games from my apps in Windows.  Many of these games rely on local files for configurations.

This is currently how I run/execute files outside of my application

```
Process r = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + gamePATH);
```

I have also tried just putting `gamePath` as the command, yet I still get this error from the halo PC game:

```
Cannot Find "C:\...Directory containing my Java app...\config.txt"
```

It seems the "current directory" when java executes is the location where it is running from. I tried this with no progress:

```
Process a = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cd " + gamePATH.subSequence(0, gamePATH.lastIndexOf("\\")+1));
```

Which would on the command line set the current directory to the directory containing the executable. Again that did not work, so if possible any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: See [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) (& implement the recommendations therein).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to look at [Process Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  In particular, you want to set the working directory using the `ProcessBuilder.directory(File)` method.  You execute it using the `start()` method.

For example:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("theExecutable");
pb.directory(new File("the/working/directory/path"));
final Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - don´t forget to specify complete path to your file in the ProcessBuilder instance.

For example:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/FolderName/SubFolderName/ExecutableFileName.exe");
pb.directory(new File("C:/FolderName/SubFolderName"));
final Process p = pb.start();
```